# How to get a specific object from Farbic.js and read the type

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How do you get a specific object from Fabric.js, and determine which one you got? Like calling `canvas.getSelectedObject()` and then determining if the
returned object is an `IText` or a `Circle` or something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the object `type` property. You can use it like this:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
switch(obj.type) {
   case "circle":
   //stuff to do if selection is a circle
   
   break;
   case "itext":
   //stuff to do if selection is a itext
   
   break;
}
```

Comment: Yep like this yeah :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `instanceof` may be what you want.

```
var c = new fabric.Circle()
console.log(c instanceof fabric.Circle) // true
```

Comment: I mean like when a object is selected in the canvas and then detect if it's an specific type of like IText or circle like that